# Use `this` in object "Unexpected token this"

Tags: javascript, object, this

I am using an object for DOMString to set the DOM. I use `this` to pointed to the `init` but it shows `Unexpected token this`. I am learning javaScript. Please help me how to use it. Thank you very much.

```js
let imageView = {

init: function () {
    // store pointers to our DOM elements for easy access later
    let DOMstrings = {
        containerElem: '#cat',
        nameElem: '#cat-name',
        imageElem: '#cat-img',
        countElem: '#cat-count'
    },
    this.catElem = document.getElementById(this.DOMstrings.containerElem);
    this.catNameElem = document.getElementById(this.DOMstrings.nameElem);
    this.catImageElem = document.getElementById(this.DOMstrings.imageElem);
    this.countElem = document.getElementById(this.DOMstrings.countElem);
};
```

Comment: Local variables are not made properties of the `this` object (if it's an object at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma after `DOMstrings` object which should be a semicolon.

Try this:

```
let imageView = {

    init: function () {
        // store pointers to our DOM elements for easy access later
        let DOMstrings = {
            containerElem: '#cat',
            nameElem: '#cat-name',
            imageElem: '#cat-img',
            countElem: '#cat-count'
        };
        this.catElem = document.getElementById(DOMstrings.containerElem);
        this.catNameElem = document.getElementById(DOMstrings.nameElem);
        this.catImageElem = document.getElementById(DOMstrings.imageElem);
        this.countElem = document.getElementById(DOMstrings.countElem);
    }
```

Comment: It shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'containerElem'` after I changed it.

Comment: try now, I updated my answer; your `DOMStrings` was badly referenced

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: The semicolon in the last line is incorrect though.

Comment: @FelixKling that's right, I copied. I think he realized when he run the code :)